# Flutter - app to handle multiple photos in Base64 format

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter app which needs to be able to handle multiple photos (around 20) which are converted to Base64 and sent to the API. I am using Hydrated Cubit (with access to ApplicationDocumentsDirectory not RAM) to temporarily store the pictures before they are sent to the API. The snag with the API is that I have to send all the pictures in one session which means that I am storing MB's of data on the phone (it can be in excess of 1GB which will crash many weaker phones).

Do you have any hints on handling such vast amounts of data without crashing the app? I cannot change anything on the API so unfortunately solutions such as Firebase are not implementable.

Comment: Hi, did you solved your problem maybe?

Comment: Hello, I am still struggling a bit with this. One optimization was to  remove a silly debugPrint which used too much memory, another, for stability reasons, was to keep the photos referenced in the storage and if the app crashes re-create Base64 only before sending. Apart from this I am somehow hoping that maybe webp compression (when it comes) could help a bit. 
Your thooughts?

Comment: I had something similar, just 10 images, and single API call. Solved it by reducing Image quality